# Apache kafka : how to find difference between queue and pub/sub programatically

Tags: java, kafka-consumer-api, kafka-producer-api

How to know the difference between queue and pub/sub in a programmatic manner and my project requires queue concept. 
can you please provide a sample queue program in java ?

Comment: it is not important if you want to write a code in java, c# or any other languages. you can use any of the queue systems available. you can even use Microsoft service bus- Queue https://azure.microsoft.com/en-us/documentation/articles/service-bus-java-how-to-use-queues/

Comment: can you please provide a sample code for apache kafka queue using java?

Comment: how consumer will receive messages from queue.

Answer (score 1):

As I wrote in the comments, Kafka implements a Pub-Sub algorithm. It is not a queue and the mechanism is not event-based.

Data producers will publish the new data to Kafka, and the consumers will ask Kafka to give them messages after Id=x. Messages will not be removed after the system approved that they has been received. Kafka simply don't care about it. If it is ok with you, you can use it like this:

[produces sample](https://cwiki.apache.org/confluence/display/KAFKA/0.8.0+Producer+Example)

[Consumer sample](https://cwiki.apache.org/confluence/display/KAFKA/Consumer+Group+Example)

The implementation of this service is almost the same as Microsoft Event-Hub and Amazon Kinesis.

If you need a queue, you need to use a system that implement queue functionalities like Microsoft service bus -queue, [java sample](https://azure.microsoft.com/en-us/documentation/articles/service-bus-java-how-to-use-queues/) or any other queue system

Comment: I have multiple consumers,

1. When i send multiple requests from those consumers with a an unique ID to a broker, how producer will generate responses to those unique ID's individually  ?
2. How producer will identify when those unique ID requests coming to the broker  ?
3. What is the relation between a producer and consumer ?

Comment: The only relation between producers and consumers in Kafka are the topics (and partitions): producers produce to topics/partitions and consumers subscribe to topics/partitions. If you need, you could have one topic per consumer but usually topics are used for things like page hits, user registration, etc.